# where is data directory in Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

In other languages (for example C#)we have a data directory (directory that our program's source file is in it) and we can put images,database,sound files in that directory and use them in program.

What is the equivalent here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anywhere. Or in the folder with your project. Just drag-and-drop the files you need to your project

Answer (score 0):

In iOS development, in general, the images, sound files, etc., are added to `Resources` group in Xcode. But physically it can be in any folder inside the project.